# XMPPFramework - Retrieve name associated with a JID

Tags: ios, xmpp, openfire, xmppframework

In Openfire users are created with a "Username" (which is used as the basis for the JID) and a descriptive "Name". How does one retrieve the Name for a given JID in XMPP? I'm using XMPPFramework.

Answer (score 1):

You may retrieve a user's Display Name using his JID from **`XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject`** like this:

```
XMPPJID *userJID = @"shakespeare";

XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject *user = [[[self appDelegate] xmppRosterStorage]
                                           userForJID:userJID
                                           xmppStream:[[self appDelegate] xmppStream]
                                 managedObjectContext:[[self appDelegate] managedObjectContext_roster]];

NSString *userDisplayName = user.displayName;
```

Comment: Thanks for the post, but you're answer is the same as Robert's below. The issue is that when creating a user, OpenFire allow the administrator to specify a "Name" in addition to the username, and there does not appear to be a way to look up that information via XMPP.

Comment: @stdout Yes, I'm aware of Openfire's settings having "username" and "name" input fields for a user - I use them too. The code above allows me to interact with a list of my fetched users from server's roster and retrieve their displayName (which is also their "Name" as reflected on the server). Question is, how are you fetching your users?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the CoreData portion of the roster when setting up the XMPPFramework? You can get the user via the JID from the storage class that is set (for example, the XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage).

From here, you can get the user stored from the roster request via the storage class such as:

[xmppStorage userForJID:jid ...]

and from here, the resulting object (XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject) has fields for 'nickname', 'displayName', etc. Some information can also be obtained from the associated vCard for that JID.

Comment: For some reason displayName the same as the JID, and nickname is blank. I also tried pulling the vCard, but every field is nil. Does the server automatically create vCards, or they start out blank and need to be populated manually? I'm pulling the vCard like so:
    `XMPPvCardTemp *vCard = [[[self appDelegate] xmppvCardTempModule] vCardTempForJID:user.jid shouldFetch:YES];`

Comment: That depends on what the server is returning really - the vCards need to be populated either manually, or from data on the server before it sends it out. You can tell what is in the result via the result from the fetch, which will contain an <item> for each user (with fields like 'jid', 'name'). Is the name here being returned with the same jid as well?

Comment: Ok, doesn't look like it populates the vCards (unless you are LDAP integrated). Once I manually populated a vCard I was able to read the info. So I think I'll just populate the user's vCard as part of the user provisioning process.